# Trouble when using @font-face

Tags: html, css, fonts

I've been struggling with using the @font-face attribute in CSS. I finally have it working but not quite the way I'd like it to work.

Whenever I use @font-face I have to leave my CSS file in the root directory. I cannot have a folder inside my main folder called "css" where I can keep my main CSS file and anything else related to it.

For example, this is how I have to set it up for it to work:

http://i.gyazo.com/a7386867a4fb61876b9ec3410e1909fa.png

that's how it's currently set up and it's working fine.

But if I were to add my CSS file into a new folder like so:

http://i.gyazo.com/97a3e9fc867fb37943709c0b5ab2dd1d.png

that no longer works and I have no idea why. I'm assuming it's something to do with the directory location path, but I'm not sure how to resolve this issue. Could anyone explain to me how I'd get @font-face to work while keeping my CSS in another folder inside my root folder?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Locations in CSS are relative to the CSS-file itself, so in your case it would be something like this;

```
@font-face{
src:url(../swag.ttf);
/*More CSS Code Here*/
}
```

Comment: Oh, I was thinking they were relative to the root directory. Okay, thank you very much SZenC.

Comment: Sure, how do I do that?

Comment: You should click the checkmark beside the answer to toggle it from grey to green.